# Using DataContract on a subclass and not parent class

Tags: vb.net, datacontract, datamember

I am trying to implement a json serializer on some of my classes.  These classes inherit from some legacy code that I cannot change and do not have any references to DataContract or DataMember.

Is it possible for me to only have the subclass be serialzed?  When I call WriteObject, I get an exception that complains about a parent class not being serializable.  However, I don't want to serialize any members of the parent classes.